# identify HTML page using PHP

Tags: php, html

Is there a way to identify different HTML pages using PHP, For example I want to know from which page data is submitted so that i can make some logic using PHP,

If i had a example.html & example2.html pages both submitting to logic.php, Now if the data comes from example.html

```
$data = Array();

$data['template'] $_POST['example'];
$data['template'] $_POST['example2'];
```

So the logic would be like

```
if(LOGIC){
     $data['template'] $_POST['example'];
}else{
     $data['template'] $_POST['example2'];
}
```

But I am not sure how to identyfie particular pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you include a hidden field into the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenfield" value="example1">
```

and

```
if($_POST['hiddenfield']=="example1") {
} else {
}
```

or you use the referer

```
if(substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"example.htm")) {
} else
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

> 'HTTP_REFERER' The address of the page (if any) which referred the
>   user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all
>   user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify
>   HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Both have their pros and cons, and both can of course be faked by the user...

Comment: Perfect, works for very well, when you say taken bu the user for example....right click view page source and edit the hidden field value or name...?

Answer (score -1):

Something like this would work, but whether it's the best approach is a different matter.

```
if (isset($_POST['example)) {
    data['template'] $_POST['example'];
} else {
    $data['template'] $_POST['example2'];
}
```

Comment: OK but how does this identify the data source from particular page...?

Comment: On the assumption that one page has an input name=example and the other has an input name=example2. Specifically doing this with a hidden input is better (@Alexander), and his point about this being easy to fake is what I meant by whether this is the best approach at all.